# LibGDX/Android development: Managing cameras across multiple screens

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

I have an android application consisting of 4 different screens. I am currently creating a new camera for each screen. Each of these screens have the same height and width. Is there a better way to handle this camera, rather than creating a new one for each screen, or is that necessary?

Comment: A `Camera` is pretty lightweight. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 :just read the documentation and specially cam.unproject(); you will realize how light it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a class like GameObjects and declare there your public static camera.

```
public static Camera camera;
```

Now in every screen you got, in the show method you would probably need to reset what you changed to it.
Example, if your camera was moving in a screen, you might want to set the position of the camera again in the show method (same thing about zoom, rotation etc).
You call your camera functions with GameObjects.camera, ex: GameObjects.camera.update();

I create a camera and spritebatch for every screen I have, and it's ok! Don't worry too much about it.
I don't really think that making just one camera is a good ideea anyways.